# Rails 5 using will_paginate to create a load more button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

So I'm trying to create a load more button (not infinite scroll although some simple js tweaks could make it so). I'm using the will_paginate gem in Rails 5.

Its currently all working as expected except when I click load more it loads the next page posts twice e.g:
**Load more >
Post 4,
Post 5,
Post 6,
Post 4,
Post 5,
Post 6**

FYI my 'posts' are @links:

**links_controller.erb**

```
def index
  @links = Link.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**views/links/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="link-wrap">
  <%= render @links %>
</div>
<% if @links.next_page %>
  <div class="link more">
    <%= link_to 'Load More', links_path(:page => @links.next_page), :class => 'next_page', :remote => true if @links.next_page %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**pagination.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('.next_page').on 'click', (e) ->
   e.preventDefault()
   url = $(this).attr('href')
   $.getScript(url)
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('.link-wrap').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
<% if @links.next_page %>
  $('.next_page').attr('href','<%= links_path(:page => @links.next_page) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.more').remove();
<% end %>
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it would be rendering the links twice when 'load more' is clicked. This seems like a really simple thing but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1):

So it was a stupid error of course.

Remove the line on index.html.erb:

```
:remote => true if @links.next_page
```

So now it looks like this:

```
<div class="link-wrap">
  <%= render @links %>
</div>
<% if @links.next_page %>
  <div class="link more">
  <%= link_to 'Load More', links_path(:page => @links.next_page), :class => 'next_page' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

All works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the server console, you can actually see two requests coming in, one triggered by your `:remote => true` enabled link and other from your custom ajax. Actually you don't need any `js` to make this work. Just remove that click function from your `pagination.js.coffee` or remove `:remote => true` from the link. After all both are doing the same thing. Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Anees,

Thanks for the answer. Yes I saw my mistake just after I posted. It's always the small things :)